# PHP: changing label value

Tags: php, html, label

I'm trying to change the value of an HTML label every time you submit a value from a text box, but for some reason when I submit a number, nothing changes. Here's the HTML snippet:

```
<div>
    <form style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom:5%">
      Score:
      <input type="number" name="score"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="calcScore">
      <input type="submit" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel">
    </form>
    <span>
      <label class="scorePlate"><?php echo $player1Score?></label>
      <label class="scorePlate"><?php echo $player2Score?></label>
    </span>
```

and the PHP function:

```
function calcScore()
{
    $playerThrow = $_GET["score"];
    $player1Score = $playerThrow;
}
```

Can anyone explain why it doesn't change anything when I submit a number?

Comment: Have you got a closing </div> tag in your code and just didn't paste it right, or is it missing from your code? That might be your issue...

Comment: Because `$player1Score` or `$player2Score` doesn't seem to be returned from your `calcScore` function - Which means they won't receive the GET value other than inside the function it self.

Comment: Bad paste, it's there, and it's the same

Comment: You have no `$player2Score` variable

Comment: It's in the php section, but the function isn't affecting it, so I don't expect it to

Comment: @Reaper9806 Please could you let me know the code from where you set the value of $player1Score and $player2Score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `calcScore()` directly from the page, rather than an outside file then you need to call it like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="calcScore()">
```

If you are calling it from an outside file you will probably need to call the function within the file, like so:

```
function calcScore()
{
    $playerThrow = $_GET["score"];
    $player1Score = $playerThrow;
}
calcScore();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong from attribute in input tag of submit. Change below line

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="calcScore">
```

with

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="calcScore">
```

Form more detail about input formaction attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp

In current code, on form submit it doesn't found action and in result you don't see the output.

Answer (score 0):

If your url was in the form: site.com?player1=12&player2=15
Then we could do this following code to grab both:

```
function calcScore($score)
{
    $playerThrow = $_GET[$score];
    return $playerThrow;
}

<label class="scorePlate"><?php echo calcScore(player1) ?></label>
<label class="scorePlate"><?php echo calcScore(player2) ?></label>
```

This might not be exactly as your url is set up but shows how you need to go about it. You need to be returning the value from the function (or just not use a function at all so $playerThrow can be accessed)